# Use function from future presto version

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

`binomial_cdf(numberOfTrials, successProbability, value) → double` is available in the current version of Presto, but not in version 0.217

**Is there any way I can copy the implementation of this function into my sql code?**

---

Background:

- current https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/math.html
- 0.217 https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/math.html

> Athena engine version 2 is based on Presto 0.217.

see [aws-docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/presto-functions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Athena flavour of Presto [does not list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/language-reference.html) `CREATE FUNCTION` as supported DDL operation. Though you can create and use a [user defined function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-udf.html) (UDF) referencing some lambda.